# Checkstyle rule to enforce empty line separation for class sections

Tags: java, checkstyle

From time to time I see on code reviews such definitions

```
public class EntityConverter {
    private static final int FIRST_VERSION = 1;
    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository repository;

    public void someMethod() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and/or

```
public class EntityConverter {
    private static final int FIRST_VERSION = 1;

    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository repository;
    public void someMethod() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

How to enforce guys to add 1 empty line between class sections (between constants, variables, methods, etc.)?

Comment: what is ur IDE?

Comment: @Salman it doesn't matter. This check has to be at CI server.

Comment: It is a clean code measurement. Why a CI server should be able to detect it?
Do you have any solution to define it for a CI?

Comment: @Salman cause we have Checkstyle checks like GitHub PR code style pre-checks at CI. All PRs must pass Checkstyle rules successfully before be merged into the main brunch.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your best bet would be the [EmptyLineSeparator](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#EmptyLineSeparator) check. According to its docs, it:

> checks for empty line separators after header, package, all import declarations, fields, constructors, methods, nested classes, static initializers and instance initializers.

Configure like this:

```xml
<module name="EmptyLineSeparator"/>
```

The `tokens` property controls where you want the empty lines. (At least you can choose from a list of places.)

You need at least Checkstyle 5.8, better 6.18 or later.

Comment: It's very close what I need but it doesn't distinguish `static final` constants and just fields.

Comment: I understand, but that‘s all you‘re gonna get unless you‘re willing to write your own custom check.

Comment: Besides writing your own check, you can ask Checkstyle to incorporate your changes into it if it makes sense for others or you can extend the existing check yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find anything already implemented, so I wrote a regex for this check.

Quick solution with multiline regex (the code should be well formatted):

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value="^([^\n ]+ )*(class|interface|enum) [^{]*\{\n[^\n}]"/>
    <property name="message" value="Leave empty row after class/interface/enum definition!"/>
    <property name="severity" value="error"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="groovy,java"/>
</module>

<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value="[^\n{]\n\}\n"/>
    <property name="message" value="Leave empty row before end of class/interface/enum!"/>
    <property name="severity" value="error"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="groovy,java"/>
</module>
```

There are a lot of threads and discussions about this:

- https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/5313
- https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/3379
- https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/3923